# New version of Android studio not showing colors

Tags: android

I updated Android Studio to version 2023 2-1 and I can no longer see the colors.
in the previous version I can see the colors like the image below

[image]

But now in the modern version I cannot see the colors like the picture below

[image]

Please help me to fix this problem